# Add project repo for an edited jar in Eclipse Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a legacy project that I'd like to convert to a Maven project for dependency management.

The problem is, that I have one jar (fop-1.1.jar) that I had to edit. It differs from the one that is publicly available and I only have it locally. But I need it this way.

What I tried to do, following several similar how-to's, it to create a fake Maven repo inside the project (local repo is no good, because several people work on that project and the solution has to be self-contained on Git) and reference this repo from the pom.xml. Sounds like the way to go for me, but it doesn't work. Eclipse show the *project repo* grayed-out :(

What am I missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

BTW: this is what I tried to follow: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies

Comment: what you try to do, is simply upload your artifact to a public repository. am i wrong? if so, the easiest way is to use OSSRH, for example, and use it to upload to Maven Central. but you have guidelines for that as you use public repo. HTH.

Comment: No, not onto a public repo, I'm trying to setup a local fake repo in a folder inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest another way: When we need to "edit" a jar, we give it a special version number like `1.1-edited` instead of `1.1.`. Then we can easily upload it to our normal Maven repository and use it. Maven even makes sure that you do not accidentally load both versions in the same project because the edit is only in the version number.

Comment: That makes sense, only that I don't have my own repository server to upload to. I only use Maven central and this is the only case I need special treatment.

Answer (score -2):

I guess what you need is a private maven server(I guess it exists), and then execute command to deploy jar( before deploy, check your account has privileges)

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=${jarFilePath} -DgroupId=${groupID} -DartifactId=${artifactId} -Dversion=${version} -Durl=${privateServerURL} -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=${privateServerURLInYourMavenSettings.xml}
```

,
after deploy successfully, add maven dependency

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${groupID}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
                <version>${version}</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, but no, I don't have a private Maven server, and I don't want to setup one, to be honest. From what I read, this SHOULD be possible with just a directory, no?